# Make Memory window auto update changed values in visual studios

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm getting started using the debugger for assembly code in Visual Studios 2013. In class my professor uses 2010 version and when values change in his code the memory windows automatically shows those changes highlighted in red like this video: https://youtu.be/BXev6625-Us?t=2m30s

When I run my debugger with the memory window open it doesn't update anything automatically and I can't find the option to change this anywhere. How do I get the memory window to display changes in red like the video?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an option you have to turn on, it should happen automatically.  Likely the reason you don't see the memory window displaying changes in red is that it isn't displaying the memory range of the memory you are modifying.  In the video you can see that the professor searched for an address in the address field.

You should look up the address of the memory (e.g. in the video if you wanted the memory window to find the address of sumval you can enter &sumval in the address search bar and it will scroll the memory window to that location).